# DAX - Different Granularities

Tags: ssas, dax

I have a Diff Grain Type Question.
I have a Fact table with 2 measures - Amount and Share_amount

EG

```
Name    Location    Amount  Share_amount
John    Ireland     100     50
John    UK          100     50
fred    USA         200     200
Bob     france      300     150
Bob     spain       300     150
```

I'd like to display the Amount but SubTotal/Total by Share_amount

In the pivot I'd like to see:

```
John        100
John Total  100
fred        200
Fred total  200
Bob         300
Bob Total   300
```

I know I can Blank() the amount if ISFILTERED() Location
But I'd like to show the amount (unshared) but keep the totals correct

Is there any way to do this in DAX

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just use SUM(Fact[Share_Amount])? Even if the location is not filtered you will get the sum of the share_amount for each name which is equal to the amount. Could you explain better your filtering requeriments in order to help you.

Comment: Thats a very good point - I should clarify - I actually want to show the Amount even if the location is selected but sum based on the share_amount. My DAX is incorrect as you point out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is something like this:

```
DEFINE MEASURE 'Fact'[RealAmount] =
    IF (
        COUNTROWS ( VALUES ( Fact[Location] ) ) = 1,
        SUM ( Fact[Amount] ),
        SUM ( Fact[Share_amount] )
    )
```

It is not tested but should work, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks - Thats what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

Here what i'm thinking - Can anyone comment if this will work or not:

```
DEFINE MEASURE 'Fact'[RealAmount] =
IF (
    NOT (
        ISFILTERED ( 'Fact'[Location])
        )
    ,
    SUM ( Fact[Amount] )
    ,
    SUM ( Fact[Share_Amount] )
)
```